# Vector Assert assigned color not working in smartphone

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

In Android studio I created vector asset image and set color as white it shows fine in preview and also working fine in AVD. If I installed it in smart phone it shows black color. Images are linked below.

Vector code for brands image `assert code`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="70dp"
android:height="70dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/white"
    android:pathData="M21.41,11.58l-9,-9C12.05,2.22 11.55,2 11,2L4,2c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v7c0,0.55 0.22,1.05 0.59,1.42l9,9c0.36,0.36 0.86,0.58 1.41,0.58 0.55,0 1.05,-0.22 1.41,-0.59l7,-7c0.37,-0.36 0.59,-0.86 0.59,-1.41 0,-0.55 -0.23,-1.06 -0.59,-1.42zM5.5,7C4.67,7 4,6.33 4,5.5S4.67,4 5.5,4 7,4.67 7,5.5 6.33,7 5.5,7zM17.27,15.27L13,19.54l-4.27,-4.27C8.28,14.81 8,14.19 8,13.5c0,-1.38 1.12,-2.5 2.5,-2.5 0.69,0 1.32,0.28 1.77,0.74l0.73,0.72 0.73,-0.73c0.45,-0.45 1.08,-0.73 1.77,-0.73 1.38,0 2.5,1.12 2.5,2.5 0,0.69 -0.28,1.32 -0.73,1.77z" />
</vector>
```

Vector code for favorites image `assert code`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:height="70dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/white"
    android:pathData="M16.5,3c-1.74,0 -3.41,0.81 -4.5,2.09C10.91,3.81 9.24,3 7.5,3 4.42,3 2,5.42 2,8.5c0,3.78 3.4,6.86 8.55,11.54L12,21.35l1.45,-1.32C18.6,15.36 22,12.28 22,8.5 22,5.42 19.58,3 16.5,3zM12.1,18.55l-0.1,0.1 -0.1,-0.1C7.14,14.24 4,11.39 4,8.5 4,6.5 5.5,5 7.5,5c1.54,0 3.04,0.99 3.57,2.36h1.87C13.46,5.99 14.96,5 16.5,5c2,0 3.5,1.5 3.5,3.5 0,2.89 -3.14,5.74 -7.9,10.05z"/>
</vector>
```

module:app`build gradle code`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.binarystore.project1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'

//For cardview
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'

//For Google Map
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'

//For Floating button menu
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

compile group: 'com.github.VyacheslavShmakin', name: 'material-searchview', version: '1.1.0'


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':customfont')
}
```

need like this

[image]

but shown like this

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html this link says that you have to use support library if you want to support vector asset below api level 21 , what api are you using on smarthphone? and are you using support library?

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar share your  vector asset code need to check how you set color code....

Comment: @Hasnain I uploaded my code Sir.

Comment: My smartphone is HTC Desire 620G 4.4.2Version. It was worked earlier this morning after I open this project again. I am facing this issue Sir. @MuhibPirani

Comment: Can you provide vector image

Answer (score 1):

```
<vector xmlns:android=enter code here"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="70dp"
android:height="70dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M21.41,11.58l-9,-9C12.05,2.22 11.55,2 11,2L4,2c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v7c0,0.55 0.22,1.05 0.59,1.42l9,9c0.36,0.36 0.86,0.58 1.41,0.58 0.55,0 1.05,-0.22 1.41,-0.59l7,-7c0.37,-0.36 0.59,-0.86 0.59,-1.41 0,-0.55 -0.23,-1.06 -0.59,-1.42zM5.5,7C4.67,7 4,6.33 4,5.5S4.67,4 5.5,4 7,4.67 7,5.5 6.33,7 5.5,7zM17.27,15.27L13,19.54l-4.27,-4.27C8.28,14.81 8,14.19 8,13.5c0,-1.38 1.12,-2.5 2.5,-2.5 0.69,0 1.32,0.28 1.77,0.74l0.73,0.72 0.73,-0.73c0.45,-0.45 1.08,-0.73 1.77,-0.73 1.38,0 2.5,1.12 2.5,2.5 0,0.69 -0.28,1.32 -0.73,1.77z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: some time rendering issue occur use  android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF" instead of  android:fillColor="@color/white" This should fix your problem

Comment: Thanks , Sir. I tried the (android:tint="@android:color/white") it is working fine now. Thanks for your help Sir.

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar if its working for you than you up vote my ans.

Answer (score 0):

> Your vector image path is not proper(rendering issue), please delete the vector assets and try to upload again.
>   Else you have to create new vector asset, better to create new vector asset

Comment: Thanks Sir, I tried this now but still not working Sir.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file at the Views where you display your icons just set:

```
android:tint="@android:color/white"
```

This should fix your problem

Comment: Glad I could help you out :)